# How can I take the unique rows of a Huggingface Dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, huggingface-datasets

Huggingface Datasets have a `unique` method, which produces a list of unique vals for a particular column.  This method is very fast.

I'd like to do something similar, with two differences:

1. I need not just the first column (`id`) but also another column (`answer`).  For every `id`, each `answer` is the same, so it's irrelevant, for a given `id`, which row we get `answer` from.
2. I'd like the result to be a Dataset, not a list, because there are a lot of values and I'd rather not load them all into Python memory.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please add an example (input dataset and expected output)? I am not sure if I fully understand your scenario. Do you have a dataset with duplicate `ids` but the answer column has the same value for every row of the whole dataset?

Comment: Perhaps this can solve it: https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/sql_on_arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know/understand from the current [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process), there is no way to do this unless you iterate twice from the dataset (without converting to pandas) and without using intermediate variables. I also read that other developers ran into the same [problem](https://bytemeta.vip/repo/huggingface/datasets/issues/2514), seeming like deduplication is not that straightforward as one would expect.

At the time of writing this comment, there isn't any way in HF alone DIRECTLY to achieve what you want, unless you want to use pandas and then reconvert.

If you still want to use only HF (without pandas), this could be a potential solution:

I would approach it this way (you do need an intermediate list)  :

```
    initial_list = dataset.filter(lambda example: example['id'], example['answer'])
    _ , unique_indices = np.unique(initial_list, return_index=True, axis=0)
    filtered_dataset = dataset.select(unique_indices.tolist())
```

PS: I can understand/expect that this is not something you desired, but unfortunately there really isn't any built-in/off-the-shelves pure HF solution.

Comment: I would use `map` and not `filter` in the first instruction.